# Parsing Multiple JSON Strings to Objects using json-simple

Tags: java, json, parsing, sockets, stream

I have a socket server running, which will emit json strings for clients. I tried to use json-simple for parsing them. But, the problem I face is that, the server doesn't have any delimiter character to segregate json strings. So, my json-simple JSONParser throws ParseException.

As an alternate, I tried to use json-smart. But, in this case, the JSONParser returns only the first object and ignores rest of the string.

I'm new to this json parsing stuff. It would be great if people can direct me to correct way of handling json string streams.

**Edit: - Adding JSON String and Sample Code**

```
{"type":"response","id":"1","result":[true,0]}{"type":"response","id":"2","result":[true,1]}
```

Currently this method returns the single object when I use json-smart and null when json-simple is used.

```
public JSONObject getResponse(JSONObject request) {
    String s = null;
    Socket soc = null;
    PrintWriter sout = null;
    BufferedReader sin = null;
    try {
        soc = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9090);
        sout = new PrintWriter(soc.getOutputStream());
        sin = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream()));
        sout.println(request.toJSONString());
        sout.flush();
        s = sin.readLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        try {
            sin.close();
            sout.close();
            soc.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    Object response = null;
    try {
        response = JSONValue.parseWithException(s.toString());
    }catch (ParseException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return (JSONObject) response;
```

Thanks in advance,

Kaja

Comment: Please post json-strings emit by your server.Also post your code if possible

Comment: @Prateek I have updated my question to include the sample json string I get from server and the code I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution using [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonRelease20). Here is the code that worked for me.

```
MappingJsonFactory factory = new MappingJsonFactory();
JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(soc.getInputStream());
JsonToken curToken = parser.nextToken();
if (curToken != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
    System.err.println("Not in start object!, Exiting...");
    return null;
}
while (runParser.get() == true) {
    if (curToken == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
        TreeNode node = parser.readValueAsTree();
        System.out.println(node.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println(node);
    }
    curToken = parser.nextToken();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kaja Mohideen! It's working with a small change in while loop. 
This code works perfectly. In my case input json is in file. 
libs used : jackson-core, jackson-annotation and jackson-databind

```
    MappingJsonFactory factory = new MappingJsonFactory();
    JsonParser parser = null;
    File file = new File("jsontest.txt");
    try {

        parser = factory.createParser(file);
        JsonToken curToken = parser.nextToken();
        if (curToken != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            System.err.println("Not in start object!, Exiting...");

        }
        while (parser.hasCurrentToken()) {
            if (curToken == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
                TreeNode node = parser.readValueAsTree();
                System.out.println(node);
            }
            curToken = parser.nextToken();
        }
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```